# Error with Converting Struct

Tags: c++, function, struct, compiler-errors

I am trying to read in a huge data set of lastnames firstnames and ssn's. When I try to point to my struct it says it is trying to convert my single_info struct from individualf to singleinfo ...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct single_info {
   string firstnames[6000];
   string lastnames[6000];
   string socialsecurity[6000];
   double gpa;
};

void ScanInFile(istream &, struct single_info, int *total);
void Outputfile(ostream &, struct single_info, int *total);
```

Here is my struct

Here are my functions and for some reason I get error: could not convert ‘& individualf’ from ‘single_info*’ to ‘single_info’

```
void ScanInFile(istream &inputfile, struct single_info *individualf, int *total)
{
        int i=0;

   while(!inputfile.eof()){
      inputfile >> individualf->socialsecurity[i];
      inputfile >> individualf->firstnames[i];
      inputfile >> individualf->lastnames[i];
      i++
   }

      *total = i;
}

void Outputfile(ostream &outputfile, struct single_info *individualf, int *total)
{
   for(int i=0; i < *total; i++){
      outputfile << individualf->socialsecurity[i];
      outputfile << individualf->firstnames[i];
      outputfile << individual->lastnames[i];
   }

   outputfile << endl;
}
```

Comment: `while(!inputfile.eof()){` Whoops...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the declarations of `ScanInFile` and `Outputfile` say that they take a `struct single_info` as their parameter type. It looks like you meant for that to be `struct single_info*` (which would match your definitions). Whatever code is attempting to call your functions can only see the declarations and is trying to pass a `single_info*` even though it asks for just a `single_info`.

Note that putting `struct` before a struct identifier is unnecessary in C++.

Comment: The declaration just before my main program? Or the prototype of the function before its definition?

Comment: @user3078582 In the first snippet of code in your question. Look at the declarations of `ScanInFile` and `Outputfile`. The second parameter for each is not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's the prototype. It needs to be defined exactly like the function itself.